# os.remove() [WinError 32] the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process - Write in file multiple time

Tags: python, windows

I have a function that I call several times in a loop. This function writes some results to a file. Each time the same file by overwriting the old results.

```py
def mass_spectra_to_mgf(filename, mass_values_list, intensity_values_list, meta_list = None, filter_by_instrument_type = None, names=None, casnos=None):
    print(os.getpid(), flush=True)

    if (os.path.exists(filename)):
        os.remove(filename)
    with open(filename, "w") as mgf_file:
        for i in range(len(mass_values_list)):
            if (meta_list):
                databaseid, intrumenttype = meta_list[i]
                if (filter_by_instrument_type and filter_by_instrument_type != intrumenttype):
                    continue
                mgf_file.write("BEGIN IONS\n")
                mgf_file.write("DATABASEID=" + databaseid + "\n")
                mgf_file.write("INSTRUMENT=" + intrumenttype + "\n")
            else:
                mgf_file.write("BEGIN IONS\n")
            if (names != None):
                mgf_file.write("NAME=" + names[i] + "\n")
            if (casnos != None):
                mgf_file.write("CASNO=" + casnos[i] + "\n")


            for j in range(len(mass_values_list[i])):
                mass, intensity = mass_values_list[i][j], intensity_values_list[i][j]
                mgf_file.write(str(mass) + " " + str(intensity) + "\n")
            mgf_file.write("END IONS\n")
```

For the first 2 iterations, everything is going well. On the third, I get an error.

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because this file is in use by another process: './myspectra.mgf'

On the os.remove(filename) line. I use the multiprocessing python module earlier in my code but I close the Pool and the line print(os.getpid(), flush=True) always print the same pid.

I searched a lot but i cannot find any answer or way to check if the file is still open. (I open the file only in this function and the "with" should close the file...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify what iterations you're talking about? You say the exception is happening at the `os.remove` line, but that's outside the only loop in the code you've shared. Similarly, you mention using `multiprocessing`, but you haven't shared the relevant code. We almost certainly need to see the multiprocessing code to know what's going wrong with it.

Comment: Oh, I should also note that since you're opening the file with mode `"w"`, which truncates any existing contents, there's really no reason to remove the file of that name if it already exists.

Comment: @Blckknght thank you for your answer. I didn't bring more detail on the level of multiprocessing because it should not normally have a link with this function. I am using multiple processes for another step earlier in my code. When this function is called the processes are already closed. The loop is outside the function and it calls "mass_spectra_to_mgf" multiple time.

Comment: Ok ! I ll try to remove the " if (os.path.exists(filename)):
        os.remove(filename)"